snowflake File_Format to remove double quotes from txt file and load to snowflake which also has a column with Json data
I have a txt file with pipe demilited data.
One of the column has a json value like below.
"Failure: {"errors":[{"message":"Does not contain a valid address.","field":"personalizations.0.to.0.email","help":"}]}     " .
I am trying to load the file to snowflake which has both varchar and json data in it.
Issue here is ,the table is created with all columns in Varchar and file is loaded using copy into with below file format . File loads with no issues but values are retained in double quotes inside table.
CREATE or replace FILE FORMAT  STG.MKT_TEST_PIPE
COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' 
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
SKIP_HEADER = 1
 REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE,
--FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' 
-- BINARY_FORMAT = UTF8
TRIM_SPACE = TRUE 
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE 
ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' 
DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
NULL_IF = ('NULL');```

commented out --FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'  as this is failing to load file to table with error expecting '|' delimiter instead of 'e' , since its considering first and last " to have single value. Need help with either file format that will load data without quotes and also load json data. 

need an update statement that will update table to remove double quotes once they are copied into. for JSON data only start and end " needs to be removed.


The best route is to push back on whoever/whatever produces this file and ask them to correct it, since there should be an escape character for the double quotes present in the JSON. The source system failed you. If that escape character was present then this would be a clean read and you wouldn't have to do any fiddling around to cleanse it after ingestion.

How do you want the final result to look like?
Please include more sample data and results desired. What UPDATE did you try? Why didn't it work? We can help you better if you help us reproduce.
